# I am not getting any response when my credentials are wrong in catch while calling login API with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I am not getting any response while calling login api from nodejs.

I am handling the catch in frontend as well.

How to get Invalid Credentials message from backend API if credentials doesn't matched.

my Backend login API is -

```
// api to login user
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    const valid = validator.isEmail(req.body.email)

    if (valid == false) {
        var message = { "Success": 0, "Message": "Please enter a valid email." };
        res.send(message)
    }

    userObj.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            var message = { "Success": 0, "Message": "User does not exists." };
            res.send(message)
        } else {

            // console.log(bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password))
            // var message = { "Success": 1, "User": user };
            // res.send(message)

            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
                .then(isMatch => {
                    if (isMatch) {
                        const payload = {
                            name: user.name,
                            id: user._id,
                            email: user.email
                        }
                        jwt.sign(payload, 'secret', {
                            expiresIn: 3600
                        }, (err, token) => {
                            if (err) console.error('There is some error in token', err);
                            else {
                                res.json({
                                    Success: 1,
                                    token: `${token}`
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        res.json({
                            Success: 0,
                            Message: 'Invalid Credentials'
                        })
                    }
                })



        }
    })

});
```

my frontend login action code is -

```
// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = user => dispatch => {
  return axios
    .post("http://18.207.190.61:4000/login", {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    })
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage
      // Set token to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("usertoken", res.data.token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(res.data.token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(res.data.token);
      // Set current user
      localStorage.setItem("username", decoded.name);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {

      return err;

    });
};
```

finally my login component code is -

```
this.props.loginUser(user).then((res, err) => {
        if (res.Success == "0") {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: res.Message
          });
        }
});
```

How can I get message Message: 'Invalid Credentials' from backend API in front end to print.

Comment: what does it return now?

Comment: It's not returning anything..

Answer (score 1):

Please return response with status codes '200' for success and '401' for invalid credentials and try again. Axios recognises the status codes and tells if there is an error.

```
if(success)
res.status(200).json({
   Success: 1,
   token: '${token}'
})
else 
res.status(401).json({
   Success: 0, 
   Message: 'Invalid Credentials'
})
```

Try this once.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: I tried but i didn't get anything.. Can you please write some code ?

Comment: I edited the above answer. Make those changes once and check.

Comment: Yes Right credentials working fine but Wrong credentials doesn't throw any error

Comment: If status is 401, it will go into .catch part of axios. Can you see if it is going into else block of backend. print something in the else block of backend. See where it is going inside if else block

Comment: Yes it is going to else block of backend.. the problem is handling from the front end.

Comment: What is console.log(err) showing in .catch of axios ?

Comment: I am getting in console Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Success' of undefined
    at Header.js:113 -

113 line is this - if (res.Success == "0") {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: res.Message
          });
        }

Comment: Hmm...ok...so res is undefined. Do console.log(this.props.loginUser(user)) in login component

Comment: It is saying Promise Pendng and getting this -

Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:1065:15)
    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:1281:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:588:7)
Header.js:112 undefined
xhr.js:166 POST http://localhost:5000/login 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Hmm...see you got the 401 status from backend. Now what you can do is 
    'if(this.props.loginUser(user).response.status==401) console.log(Invalid Credentials);'

Comment: I am getting now  - 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

my code is - 
this.props.loginUser(user).then((res, err) => {
        if (this.props.loginUser(user).err.status == 401) {
          console.log("sorry")
        }
}

Comment: Just write 'if(this.props.loginUser(user).response.status==401) console.log(Invalid Credentials) in login component. Don't write .then

Comment: Again getting same error  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

action.js return code is - 

.catch(err => {

      return err;
      
    });

Header.is handle file is - 

if (this.props.loginUser(user).response.status == 401) {
      console.log("sorry2")
}

Comment: this.props.loginUser(user).catch(error=>if(error.response.status==401) console.log(Invalid Credentials))...try this in login component. and remove .catch in login action.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove the catch block in your login action code
2. change your login component code to

```
    this.props.loginUser(user).then((res ) => {
    if (res.Success == "0") {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        message: res.Message
      });
    }
    });
```